# Recompile Orchard Widget Module built for 1.10.2 to older 1.9.2 instance not working

Tags: orchardcms, orchard-modules

I developed a custom widget module for Orchard CMS v1.10.2 and it works fine. I can use it from the Widget menu by adding the Widget to one of the page sections such as the Content section.

I then found out the target CMS instance was v1.9.2.

So I changed the module to use .NET v4.5.1  and updated the library references. The module now compiles with no errors in my test v1.9.2 instance.

It shows up in the list of modules as something I can enable. When I enable it I see no errors in the UI or logs. When I go to the Widgets menu and try to add it to the Content section of the page, however, I do not see the widget listed.

The documentation for building a widget at the Orchard site even says the documentation was based on v1.9.2 and should work for newer versions. I checked the release notes for each version between 1.9.2 and the current release for breaking changes, but see nothing.

I don't know why the widget does not display and I do not know where to start looking. Is it my code that doesn't throw any errors and compiles fine? Is it a configuration thing, insteadm with v1.9.2? Given that I'm not clear that I have a code problem, I'm not even sure which code to post... thank you for any guidance.

Comment: Did all the necessary migrations run on the target instance? Is there absolutely nothing in the logs?

Comment: Honestly I had not really gotten into the migration stuff because my widget uses static content - there was no data model to update. I thought that was what migrations are for. But I'll check the migration stuff out more.

Comment: You technically wouldn't need migrations if you did everything manually through the Dashboard but I assumed you would have at least used them to create your Widget ContentType, attach WidgetPart and CommonPart and set the Stereotype to "Widget".

Comment: I think this is the issue. I also think perhaps that I had a Migration.cs at some point, and it ran once on my v1.10.2 instance (locally) so it setup the types and parts as needed. After that it must have been removed... but the environment was still good to go. Then my v1.9.2 instance never got the initialization that comes from having the Migration.cs stuff... and so it never knew about the types and parts that were being provided.